# How to define number of array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to remove the value from the array. But I can not determine this number. I'm sending a DELETE request with id on backend, but how to find this value in the TypeScript array.

Example of array [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXqAY.jpg)

My code  Typescript

```
  export class FileService {
public myResults: string[];
public id: number;
Url: string = "";

constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, 
public dialog: MatDialog ) {
http.get<string[]>(baseUrl + '/getAllFiles').subscribe(result => {
  this.myResults = result;

  console.log(result);
}, error => { console.log('an error occured!'); console.log(error); });
this.Url = baseUrl;
}
public fileDelete(id) {
return this.http.delete(this.Url + '/delete' + id).subscribe(
  data => {

    console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);

    const index = this.myResults.indexOf(id)
    this.myResults.splice(index, 1);
  },
```

My HTML code

```
<tr *ngFor="let myResult of myResults;">
    <td>{{ myResult.idPres }}</td>
    <td> {{ myResult.namePres }} </td>
    <td><button  type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="fileDelete(myResult.idPres)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe because your are not sending /delete/id, instead you are sending: /deleteid.

Comment: The splice function is good

Comment: @itFreak Problem in the splice function, it gives me -1 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.indexOf` is not enough to do that.

You need to use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex):

```
public fileDelete(id) {
    return this.http.delete(this.Url + '/delete' + id).subscribe(
        data => {

            console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
            // objArray is an array containing what we see in your screenShot
            const obj = this.objArray.find(result=> result.idPres === id);
            const fileName = obj.namePres;
            // now fileName is a string so it's safe to find it in a string array with indexOf
            const index = this.myResult.indexOf(fileName);
            this.myResults.splice(index, 1);
        },
```

Comment: I have an error " property 'findIndex' does not exist on type string[] "

Comment: My answer was assuming my result was containing element that looked like what we see in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXqAY.jpg
Anyway it's weird that an array instance does not have a findIndex method. How do yo build your code?

Comment: Im using angular 6, btw im trying to solve like this " this.myResults.indexOf(this.myResults.filter(obj => obj.idPres == id)[0]);" but after that i have error of idPres does not exist on type string

Comment: Yes because `this.myResult` is an array of strings, not obj with the expected data, I've edited my answer to emphasis what we miss.

Comment: thank you for help, i changed array to public myResults: any[]; and all works now!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using array of objects, you need to find index of object containing id. Replace with below one

```
const index = this.myResults.indexOf({id: id})
```

Comment: in this case i have en error " argument of type { id:any} is not assignable  to parameter  of type string "